Negative slope from new vent stack to existing vent stack
My second floor new rough fit dry vent stack is at 8’, not through roof yet, but instead of penetrating there, can I run horizontal and then pitch down to connect to an existing (1st floor) vent stack that is only 6’ high? See proposed purple line.
We got a new roof a few months ago, and I just hate to pop a vent, especially that will be usable from the front of the house.
I think water from rain will simply go down the existing vent stack.
If I cannot slope it down to connect to an existing vent, I may have the option of a horizontal run through exterior wall .

The vent stack is there to have an open air path, that kind of downward path creates a bit of trapped water that has the same properties as the trap under your sink, it will prevent air from moving through and might result in another trap being pulled dry when you flush the toilet.
You will have to make that run (mostly) horizontal with just enough drop that rain water will drain out entirely.
Or just pop that new vent higher on the roof anyway.

I'm not understanding how the downward slope will create trapped water.  Maybe I'm not understanding your answer.

I am wondering this as well.  Any condensation still has routes to either drain through waste or vent back to waste. I recently  built an entire addition as a DIYer, including all city permits.  The city was fantastic answer questions like this.  If you are already using the city, give the plumbing inspector a call.

Maybe ratchet just means that you gotta make sure the "horizontal" pipe is properly sloped?
